# Filter Results in Jquery on list and show no results message

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have a list and an input field. The script filters through the list showing/filtering matching results from the input/list.

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

If one were to type "sss" they wouldn't see a match within the list. I would then like to show a message "no results found" when there is not a match. How can I add this message?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#list-search").on("keyup click input", function () {
     if (this.value.length > 0) {
         $("#list li").hide().filter(function () {
             return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#list-search").val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
         }).show();
     } else {
         $("#list li").show();
     }
 });
});
```

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/6kzowkkv/

Comment: could you clarify your question?

Comment: Hey @David I updated the question. Does this make a little more sense on what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option. Rather than a message of not found, a count would work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#list-search").on("keyup click input", function () {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
        $("#list li").hide().filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#list-search").val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
        }).show();
         var countlistitems = $('#list > li:visible').length;
        $('.countli').html(countlistitems);
    } else {
        $("#list li").show();
    }
});
});
```